On correspondence of Ext functor and Extension Group
I have constructed the bijection between the extension group (say, $Ext(M,N)$ in an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$ with enough projectives (or injectives)) and the abelian group $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathsf{A}}^1(M,N)$. With the baer sum I am able to endow a group structure on $Ext(M,N)$, but I cannot prove that the bijection preserves addition.
This is a brief outline of my work:
Begin with a projective $F$ and an epi $F \to M$. This gives a short exact sequence $0 \to K \to F \to M \to 0$, and by projectivity of $F$ we obtain a morphism from this sequence to an extension of $N$ by $M$. With the long exact sequence of $\mathrm{Hom_{\mathsf{A}}}$, one component $k: K \to N$ of this morphism gives an element of $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathsf{A}}^1(M,N)$. Conversely, select a preimage $k' \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{A}}(K,N)$ of an element of $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathsf{A}}^1(M,N)$; this map gives an extension by the pushout of $k'$ and the inclusion map $K \to F$.
Now that the converse procedure is based on maps $K \to N$; to prove this bijection an isomorphism, one only need to check that for extensions $\mathcal{E,E'}$ with their corresponding maps $k,k'$, $\mathcal{E+E'}$ corresponds to $k+k'$. This is summarized in this diagram. However, I am not able to prove such; one attempt was to form this diagram but the intermediate $Z$ seems not to be $F$; in that sense we would have an element $\mathcal{F} \in  Ext(M,K)$ such that $\mathcal{F} + \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}$ when $\mathcal{F}$ have no reason to be zero.
My question is, is there a way to cope this? Or, is there an alternative way to prove the correspondence an isomorphism?
